# English texts with Russian translation

Tags: discussion, online-resources, resource-request

Can you give me some web sites where I can find English texts for intermediate level with translation to Russian? I going to memorize the texts to improve my speaking skill.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Alex. Questions asking for resource recommendations are usually handled here on meta. We have a [Resources for Learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) thread that might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alex, there are lots of such sites, just search in Russian for [параллельные тексты на английском и русском](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and you are sure to find something to your level and taste.

Besides you can also find some theoretical support, pros and cons of the method. They say you should read only English texts after the intermediate level. Here's one of the sites: http://www.parallango.com/ru/author/206
By the way, this is also called Ilya Frank's method, and he published a lot of books, just google the name.